# UITableView listen user scroll not its delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

There is a UITableview. When i insert a row ,i call this method

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastRow atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

To keep the newest cell show. how can i listen user scroll the tableview.
i tried add UIScrollview delegate - `scrollViewDidScroll`, but this method also listen

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try below code it is working fine for me

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Here `selectedIndex` is which you need to show.

Comment: the code work fine, but i wanna know user scroll my tableView and do some things after that